# How can I remove accelerator characters from a string?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, string, accelerator

I have a caption for a GUI control, and I want to convert it to a simple text string. Specifically, I want to remove the accelerator metacharacters.

For example (examples assume WinForms):

- Strip off single occurrences of the metacharacter: `&Yes` becomes `Yes`
- Convert double occurrences to single: `Income && Expense` becomes `Income & Expense`

My code will know whether it's dealing with the Windows Forms syntax (where the accelerator metacharacter is `&`) or WPF (where it's `_`). However, this is in back-end code, so I don't want to take a dependency on any WinForms or WPF library functions -- I need to do this using the core (non-GUI) BCL assemblies. (And at that point, I figure that anything that works for WinForms would be trivial to modify for WPF.)

I can think of several ways to do this, but it's not clear which is simplest.

What's the **simplest way** to implement this "remove metacharacters if single, de-double if doubled"?

**Update:** I had assumed that WinForms and WPF both handled these basically the same, but it turns out they don't. WinForms will strip a lone metacharacter at the end of the string (`Foo&` becomes `Foo`), but WPF will not (`Foo_` remains `Foo_`). Bonus points for an answer that addresses both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've edited (removed) my previous answer.  I think the simplest way would be this regular expression:

```
string input = "s&trings && stuf&f &";
input = Regex.Replace(input, "&(.)", "$1");
```

That correctly handles repeated ampersands as well as the case where the ampersand is the last character.

EDIT, based on additional provided information:

So the WinForms expression would be `"&(.?)"`, and the WPF expression would be `"_(.)"`.  You ask for a solution that addresses both cases, but I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your original question said that the code knows whether it's processing WPF format or WinForms format.  So I would envision a method:

```
string StripAccelerators(string s, bool isWinForms)
{
    string pat = (isWinForms) ? "&(.?)" : "_(.)";
    return Regex.Replace(s, pat, "$1");
}
```

And, yes, I realize that using a `Boolean` flag in the interface is less than ideal.  Ideally, you'd use an enumerated type, or perhaps have two separate methods.

I don't think you want to have a single regular expression that will perform both.  It's possible, but then you'll end up removing underlines from WinForms strings, or ampersands from WPF strings.

Comment: See update. This isn't correct as written (WinForms will strip a single trailing `&`), but becomes correct if you either (1) change each `&` to `_` (in which case it matches WPF behavior); or (2) change `"&(.)"` to `"&(.?)"` (in which case it matches WinForms behavior).

Comment: Yes, given the differences in behavior, it would probably be best as two different methods. But it looks like this nails it pretty effectively.