# Getting the Label text without Hotkey('&') in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys, ampersand

In my C# Winforms application, I have few labels control with hotkey set.(eg: &Name). We are using JAWS screen reader. The Label.Text always gives "&Name". Is there any way to get the label text without hotkeys('&')? I cant replace the '&' with String.empty because there are few labels with actual '&' required in it.

Comment: And these labels should have a double &&. Hint regexp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove accelerator characters from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700612/how-can-i-remove-accelerator-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: This is an accessibility issue.  I'm assuming based on your description that the screen reader is reading out the ampersand character.  What the reader presents is under its own control.  The WinForms controls support the legacy  Accessibility.IAccessible model.  You could try to create a custom label that would in turn provide a custom ControlAccessibleObject in which you override the `Value` property to make available the text without the ampersand.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way is to use **AccessibleObject.Name** property.

Ex : String text = label1.AccessibleObject.Name;

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example where '&' is required?

TrimStart will remove characters form the beginning of a string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my earlier comment, this is an accessibility issue.  The following custom `Label` exposes a new `string` property `AccessibleValue` that can be set to the text that the AccessibleObject will return as its value.

I do not know whether or not this works with the JAWS screen reader, but it did show the custom value when using the Inspect tool.

```
public class AccessibleLabel : Label
    {
    protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance()
        {
        return new LabelAccessibleObject(this);
        }

    public string AccessibleValue { get; set; }

    private class LabelAccessibleObject : ControlAccessibleObject
        {
        private AccessibleLabel myowner;
        public LabelAccessibleObject(AccessibleLabel owner)
            : base(owner)
            {
            this.myowner = owner;
            }

        public override AccessibleRole Role
            {
            get
                {
                AccessibleRole accessibleRole = base.Owner.AccessibleRole;
                if (accessibleRole != AccessibleRole.Default)
                    {
                    return accessibleRole;
                    }
                return AccessibleRole.StaticText;
                }
            }

        public override string Value
            {
            get
                {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myowner.AccessibleValue))
                    {
                    return base.Value;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    return myowner.AccessibleValue;
                    }
                }
            set
                {
                base.Value = value;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```